# JavaScript listen for all focus/blur events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

So I'd like some JavaScript which listens for all *potential* focus/blur events on the page. I can do this for click events quite easily:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) { console.log('click!') })
```

Any time any element is clicked, the event will trigger, even if the node was inserted after the event listener was added.

**I'd like to do the same for focus events, but they are only triggered on individual elements, and never bubble up to the document.**

How can I accomplish this? Is the only way to walk the DOM every few seconds and re-listen in case a new input element has been added?

Answer (score 49):

You can use the [focusin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/focusin) and [focusout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/focusout) events which bubbles up.

```
document.addEventListener('focusin', function(e) { console.log('focusin!')})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5377W/)

Comment: but this is not the event I'm trying to trigger.

Comment: what do you mean by that? it is same as the focus event

Comment: No, it isn't. It has a similar effect on the user's browser, but I'm working with the intricacies of the DOM and need to listen for the vent called 'focus'

Comment: @JacksonGariety in that case you I think you are trying something impossible as focus event by definition doesn't bubble up

Comment: @ArunPJohny This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much!

Comment: Important to know the focusin and focusout events fire before the focus and blur events, much like the mousedown and mouseup fire before click etc