# How can I monitor focus events in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to track which element gets focus in a web app. I came across the [monitorEvents](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#monitoreventsobject_events) API, but I'm having difficulty using it for `control` or `focus` events. Other events on `body` are working as expected, but not the `control` events. Any advice?

Comment: I think this existing question has the best answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572434/javascript-listen-for-all-focus-blur-events

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how exactly you want to "monitor" `control` events, but you can set [event listener breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#event-listeners) on the entire category, or individual events like `focus`. Whenever a `focus` listener runs for any node on the page, DevTools pauses on the first line of the listener.
[image: control event listener breakpoints]

Comment: When devtools breaks on the focus event, focus changes, making debugging virtually impossible for me. I'm not sure in what situation this would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to monitor focus and blur events on the entire document today.
When using `monitorEvents(document.body, 'control')` I would only see the event fired when I left the tab entirely and then refocused. I believe what's happening is that once you're focused on the body, it'll never change when you focus on child elements since the listener is at a high level and the events just bubble up to the body with no change in focus.

I tried monitoring events on a few specific child elements and saw that those triggered how I expected. So I decided to add an event listener to each element in the document and that worked well. Here's the one-liner for that.

`document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach((el)=> monitorEvents(el, 'control'))`