# Accessing full path of object mentioned in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, button, click, google-chrome-devtools, sugarcrm

I am using Chrome's DevTools JS console to debug a custom function that executes when a button is clicked. When I click on the button, I get the following message in my console:

```
[Violation] 'click' handler took XXXms
```

Is there a way I can access the full path of this (button) object that I am clicking through the console message I am getting? I assume it will be something along the lines of `App.controller.XXX`.

Comment: There's a clickable link to the actual source code at the right. Might not be helpful for code inside html, though. Anyway, this sounds like a feature request which you can open on https://crbug.com.

Comment: If you haven't done this yet, have a look at the SugarDebug tools:  https://github.com/sugarcrm/SidecarDevTools
There you should be able to see the click events in the application stream and get to the events' Sugar component/arguments. Not sure if that helps you with what you want to accomplish exactly, but it's surely worth having a look at IMHO.

Comment: Thank you @Jay, this is definitely worth taking a look at. For what its worth, I'm mostly working with version 8.0.1 (the extension is built for versions 7.x), but this is still very helpful!

Comment: @Mike Yeah, I noticed it says 7.x as well. However I'm pretty sure they actually mean >= 7, as the context is the GUI-Framework ("sidecar", which came with Sugar 7 and is also used in Sugar 8 and future versions of Sugar).
8 just didn't exist back then when that line was written. It is compatible as far as I'm aware. Either way, it's a cool tool to see event/render timings, page structure, etc. There *is* one annoying bug worth mentioning: It's toolbar icon tends to say "ON" even when it's actually not running. So if the tool doesn't seem to work, then the icon is probably lying -> click it.

Comment: @Jay Yep, already ran into that bug testing it with a 7.x version. Sidecar debug said to turn it on when the toolbar icon already said "ON", so I clicked it a couple of more times until I got it working; thanks for the heads up! I'll update with its Sugar 8.0.1 compatibility soon, though I believe you are right that it will still be compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround:

1. Enable a [event listener breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43261810/1669860) on **Mouse** > `click`.
2. Click the button. DevTools pauses in the button's click handler.
3. Evaluate `e.target` in the DevTools Console, where `e` is the name of the event object that you're passing to the handler. In other words, you might have used the name `event`, `e`, or something else.
4. Right-click the DOM element that gets returned and select **Reveal in Elements panel**.

Comment: This is a great workaround to get information about the reference to something you are performing an action on. This will be helpful to what I am looking for in the short-term, so thank you! Whether or not its possible to get the full path of the JavaScript object something such as a button is connected to remains to be seen; follow [this crbug ticket](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=868064) for updates.

Answer (score 0):

As per [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom)'s suggestion, I have opened an issue into [crbug.com](https://crbug.com/) as a feature request since what I am asking for is not yet possible.

Follow the issue [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=868064).

Comment: It's possible to get a reference to the button in the DOM. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51565495/1669860).