# I need to detect focus event on all HTML input elements on page without addEventListener and without HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, dom-events

I need to detect focus event on all HTML input elements on the page without using `addEventListener` and without `HTML attributes`

I was able to do that with the click event by:

```js
onclick = () => { 
  // do something
}
```

But when i do like that for `onfocus` it just fires when the focus occurs in the document itself.

Is there a way I could to it the same way for `onfocus` and `onchange` on input and select elements, respectively?

**EDIT**

The reason why i can't use the `HTML attributes` it's because it will be on a static script that will load through a CDN in the page. Thus, i do not have access to the HTML code itself and i can't use the `HTML attributes`.

About the `addEventListener`, I don't want use for performance issues, because i would have to loop for every elements and it would be costly for some browsers and devices memories

Furthermore, if the element on pages change dynamically, like in a SPA, i would have to listen to this change and loop through all of them again, which would cause **performance issues**.

Comment: onclick is window.onclick. Ditto onfocus. Please start by explaining us WHY you cannot use attributes and eventlisteners. Otherwise is just sounds like an X/Y problem

Comment: I agree with @mplungjan, why are you restricted from using the addEventListener?

Comment: The reason why i can't use it's because it will be on a static script that will load through a CDN in the page. 

Thus, i do not have access to the HTML code itselft and i can't use the attributes.

Comment: About the addEventListener, I don't want use for performance issues, because i would have to loop for every elements and it would be costly for some browsers and devices memories

Comment: Furthermore, if the element on pages change dynamically, like in a SPA, i would have to listen to this change and loop through all of them again, which would cause performance issues.

Comment: I would probably use something like outlined in this Stack Overflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572434/javascript-listen-for-all-focus-blur-events.

Then provide the appropriate logic for the type of elements you're choosing to add behaviour to.

So you would basically use `document.addEventListener("focus", (e) => { /* logic here */ })`

Comment: What if you set delegated listeners on the document?

Comment: What would be that @james?

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple idea using delegated listeners attached to the document.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  console.log("You clicked on " + e.target.nodeName);
}, true);

document.addEventListener("focus", (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.nodeName + " (" + e.target.name + ") has focus");
}, true);

document.addEventListener("blur", (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.nodeName + " (" + e.target.name + ") lost focus");
}, true);
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='red'>
<p>some text</p>
<input type='text' name='username'>
</div>
```